# Copying VM between projects in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm currently using windows VM instance in GCP(**project1**), i want to create same VM with data in my another project(**project2**)(project in another gmail account). The **project2** have access to my **project1** which i had setup IAM role.

So what the next step to copy the instance between the **project1** to **project2** (without loosing the data)?

Comment: If the answer was useful, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members. Check [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a VM instance from one project to another either using a custom image or using disk.

**Method 1: Using Custom image**

You have to use the following steps to create a mirror VM in another project:

1. In your source project, create a snapshot of the VM's boot disk, using one of the below command:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute snapshots create <SNAPSHOT_NAME> --source-disk <SOURCE_DISK> --source-disk-zone <SOURCE_DISK_ZONE>
   ```
2. Create a custom image from the snapshot using the following command:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute images create <IMAGE_NAME> --source-snapshot=<SOURCE_SNAPSHOT> [--storage-location=<LOCATION>]
   ```
3. In your destination project, create a VM from the custom image using the following command:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create <VM_NAME> --image-project <IMAGE_PROJECT> [--image <IMAGE> | --image-family <IMAGE_FAMILY>]
   ```

**Method 2: Using disk**

1. In your source project, create a snapshot of the VM's boot disk, using one of the below command:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute snapshots create <SNAPSHOT_NAME> --source-disk <SOURCE_DISK> --source-disk-zone <SOURCE_DISK_ZONE>
   ```
2. Then create a disk in the destination project with --source-snapshot:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute disks create <DISK_NAME> --source-snapshot <SOURCE_SNAPSHOT> --project <destination-project>
   ```
3. Create a VM based on the new disk from step 2

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create <VM_NAME> --project <destination-project> --disk name=<DISK_NAME>,boot=yes
   ```

Refer [Copying VMs between projects](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/copy-vm-between-projects#zonal-boot-disk) for information.

Comment: Im using method- 2 in step to im getting this error :  "ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.sourceSnapshot': 'https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/explore-and-go-project/global/snapshots/sanpshot-2'. The referenced snapshot resource cannot be found   "   
(logged in source project)
I m currently in source project and my destination is ```explore-and-go-project``` when i specify --project = explore-and-go-project created snapshot ```sanpshot-2``` in source project but gcp search it in destination project

Comment: Actually i fixed this by adding  ``` --source-snapshot projects/my-project/global/snapshots/sanpshot-2```

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. If the answer was useful, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members.